# return all matches in regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

```
>>> import re
>>> p=re.compile('(a(.)c)d')
```

Why does the following only return 'abcd' but not also 'aecd'? If I want to return both, how shall I do? If I only like to return `aecd`, what shall I do?

```
>>> m=p.match('abcdeaecd')
>>> m.group() 
'abcd'
>>> m.groups()
('abc', 'b')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify your RegEx, like this

```
import re
p=re.compile(r'a.cd')
```

And use `re.findall` to get all the matches, like this

```
print p.findall('abcdeaecd')
# ['abcd', 'aecd']
```

Otherwise you can use your RegEx itself and iterate over the matches like this

```
print [item.group() for item in p.finditer('abcdeaecd')]
# ['abcd', 'aecd']
```

Comment: thanks. (1)does `p.match` only return the first match? (2) What if I want to return the last match?

Comment: @Tim `match` tries to match the pattern from the beginning of the string and returns only the match found from the beginning. If your string has started with anything other than `a`, it wouldn't have matched anything

Comment: @Tim `p.match` only returns the first match. However, this answer will only return the matched strings, and will not return Match objects; in particular, you won't be able to access the capturing groups.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to use [`finditer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.finditer) instead of `match`:

```
ms = p.finditer('abcdeaecd')
    for m in ms:
        # do something with m.group or m.groups
```